# Forge Mod Development requires import manually

Tags: java, api, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Is it normal for a developer to have to find and import classes manually to a modding project? im trying to get into minecraft mod development using the mdk in eclipse to work. I've started by trying to just get a keybind in the game that says something like hello world or something. but at every step i have to go find a class within forge that allows me to do something and then import it first. is this normal or is there a way that i can skip having to manually import ever class i use?
or atleast like a website that helps you find what you are looking for as far as methods go?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal. Not much of the process is documented and it can often vary wildly between versions as they rename classes/methods.

They are all volunteers working on getting forge working with each new Minecraft version, and sometimes Mojang changes the way they approach things(the switch from 1.7.10 to 1.8 was major) or the forge team has decided on a better method to approach things and rewrote classes to better reflect this.

You'll have to look around online for examples in blogposts/fora/here if they are for another version and you can't find the classes mentioned, try to find if someone asked `how do I use ClassnameHere in forge [version.here]`

Modding isn't for the weak of heart or patience, and a lot of experimentation is required.

It can help if you decompile mods that offer a "dev" version of their mods as they are not obfuscated, and can give you working examples on how they work.